# cant get the value of input with oop js

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Hello I am trying to get the input value from a form input using oop js.

When I get the username I want to validate it but I cant get the value of username.

when I console.log(username); I either get undefined or the html markup instead of the value. What am I doing wrong?

my form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```

and my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
validateForm = {

    username : $.trim($('#username').val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')),

    checkUsernameValid : function() {
        $('#username').on('keyup change', function() {
            console.log(this.username);
            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(this.username) == false) {
                alert('bad')
            } else {
                alert('good');
            }
        });
    }
};

validateForm.checkUsernameValid();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call either `this.username = $.trim($('#username').val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''));` or `this.username = $('#username').val();` inside your `keyup event` to set the value

```js
validateForm = {

    username : $.trim($('#username').val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')),

    checkUsernameValid : function() {
        $('#username').on('keyup change', function() {
        this.username = $.trim($('#username').val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
            console.log(this.username);
            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(this.username) == false) {
               // alert('bad')
            } else {
               // alert('good');
            }
        });
    }
};

validateForm.checkUsernameValid();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```

Comment: If I define username this way will I still be able to use it again in another method?

Comment: I would say so yes, just call `validateForm.username` and that should return the value, if it has been set.

Comment: So really I could initially set the username like username : '', or username : null, because I will re define it in my method anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> *I either get **undefined** or the **html markup** instead of the value.*

As you have set the name and id attributes so it gets available in the global scope as a whole so, html element gets logged in console.

You should not bind the event in the method such way. You can call the method in the bound event and make the method to accept the value as an argument such as:

```js
validateForm = {
  username: $.trim($('#username').val().toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')),
  checkUsernameValid: function(value) { // 2. get the value
    this.username = value; // 3. set the value
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(this.username) == false) {
      console.log('bad')
    } else {
      console.log('good');
    }
  }
};
$('#username').on('keyup change', function() {
  validateForm.checkUsernameValid(this.value); // 1. pass the input value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```

Comment: I really like this answer however I get a TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined error if I use it. Any ideas why?

Comment: That might be due to not wrapping it in doc ready as the selector won't be available if script is included before the target dom elements.  Another option is move the script block at the closing of body.